# Bx slider inside Wordpress loop not working in Chrome but works in Firefox

Tags: jquery, wordpress, bxslider

I made a page for a friend based on Wordpress.

Made a slider based on the [BX Slider](http://bxslider.com/) that spits out posts from a certain category and makes it too a slider.

Funny thing is - it works perfect in Firefox , but doesnt work at all in Chrome.
Can't really figure out what seems to be the problem?

[Link to webpage.](http://www.cloudpictures.se/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Fruxelot, I investigate the issue and i found the problem in the markup, You are creating the bx slider structure using span elements in parent div i.e.

```
<div id="slider1" class="latestposts">
   <span> Stuff 1 </span>
   <span> Stuff 2 </span>
   <span> Stuff 3 </span>
</div>
```

Instead of this use div in nested elements for example

```
<div id="slider1" class="latestposts">
   <div> Stuff 1 </div>
   <div> Stuff 2 </div>
   <div> Stuff 3 </div>
</div>
```

It will fix your problem.